# Facebook API : page feeds

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I would like to integrate Facebook page's feeds to my website.
I'm trying to use the Graph API, everything works fine, but I cannot get the attached pictures (picture field).

```
/v2.6/{page_id}/feed
```

But I only get the id, created_time and message fields.
Can someone helps me with this ?

I probably miss something but I cannot found what.

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/v2.6/{page_id}/feed?fields=message,picture,...
```

You don´t get the additional fields if you don´t ask for them.

Existing fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/post